Proving that this complex integral goes to zero
Let $\lambda > \tau > 0$ be fixed parameters. Consider the complex integral:
$$I= \int_{\gamma} dz \frac{e^{-iz\tau}}{(-iz+1)(1+e^{-i\lambda z})}$$
where $\gamma$ is a semi-circle on the upper half-plane $\gamma = \{Re^{i\theta}: \theta \in [0,\pi]\}$ for some fixed $R > 0$. I want to show that this integral becomes zero in the limit $R \to \infty$. My approach is the following. First, I write $z = Re^{i\theta}$, so the integral becomes:
$$I = \int_{0}^{\pi} iR e^{i\theta}d\theta \frac{e^{iRe^{i\theta}(\lambda -\tau)}}{(-iRe^{i\theta}+1)(1+e^{i\lambda Re^{i\theta}})}$$
My idea is to estimate the absolute value of the integrand. First, because $\theta \in [0,\pi]$, we have:
$$1 \le |1+R\sin\theta| = |\operatorname{Re}(-iRe^{i\theta}+1)| \le |-iRe^{i\theta}+1| \tag{1}\label{1}$$
and, analogously:
$$1 \le |1+e^{-\lambda R\sin\theta}\cos(\lambda R\cos\theta)| = |\operatorname{Re}(1+e^{i\lambda Re^{i\theta}})| \le |1+e^{i\lambda Re^{i\theta}}| \tag{2}\label{2} $$
because $\cos(R\lambda \cos\theta)$ is always nonnegative. We also use:
$$|e^{iRe^{i\theta}(\lambda-\tau)}| = e^{-R\sin\theta(\lambda-\tau)}\tag{3}\label{3}$$
Plugging (\ref{1}), (\ref{2}) and (\ref{3}) together, we obtain:
$$|I| \le \int_{0}^{\pi}d\theta R \bigg{|}e^{i\theta}d\theta \frac{e^{iRe^{i\theta}(\lambda -\tau)}}{(-iRe^{i\theta}+1)(1+e^{i\lambda Re^{i\theta}})}\bigg{|} \le \int_{0}^{\pi}d\theta R e^{-R\sin\theta(\lambda-\tau)}$$
Because the integrand is bounded by one and goes to zero as $R \to \infty$, the result must follow from the Dominated Convergence Theorem.
My question is: is my reasoning correct? I am not entirely sure I can use the Dominated Convergence Theorem in the last step in polar coordinates and also I don't know if I am missing something in my estimates. I think the proof is correct, but I lack confidence at the moment.

DCT works fine here.
